# AppServerModuleNgFactory is not being built

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Hi I have an angular app which I converted into Angular Universal. After lots of struggle I came to a point where AppServerModuleNgFactory is undefined.

```
`AppServerModuleNgFactory`
```

is undefined when I 
    `console.log()`

When I debug the generated main.js I cannot find that class in the file at all.

Here is my build script
    `ng build --prod && ng run ui:server:production`

Answer (score 2):

AppServerModuleNgFactory is no longer available in Ivy. Instead please use AppServerModule